# Install Pgadmin4 on centos 6.5

Tags: centos6.5, pgadmin-4

I'm using CentOS 6.5. I cant install pgadmin 4, I use

```
yum -y install pgadmin4-v1
```

Error:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution 
Error: Package: pgadmin4-v1-web-1.6-2.rhel6.noarch (pgdg10)
           Requires: pgadmin4-python-flask-wtf >= 0.12
Error: Package: pgadmin4-v1-web-1.6-2.rhel6.noarch (pgdg10)
           Requires: pgadmin4-python-dateutil >= 2.5.0
Error: Package: pgadmin4-v1-web-1.6-2.rhel6.noarch (pgdg10)
           Requires: pgadmin4-python-flask-security >= 1.7.5
Error: Package: pgadmin4-v1-web-1.6-2.rhel6.noarch (pgdg10)
           Requires: python-crypto >= 2.6.1
           Available: python-crypto-2.0.1-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
               python-crypto = 2.0.1-22.el6
Error: Package: pgadmin4-v1-web-1.6-2.rhel6.noarch (pgdg10)
           Requires: python-html5lib >= 1.0b3
           Installed: python-html5lib-0.90-1.el6.noarch (@epel)
               python-html5lib = 0.90-1.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You can install pgAdmin4 on CentOS using below command,

```
yum -y install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/10/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos10-10-2.noarch.rpm
yum install pgadmin4-v2
```

Comment: I get a similar collection of errors when trying to install pgAdmin4-v2 on RHEL 6.9. :(